# m[1][/_pages/] In Guardfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd, guard

I was looking over [Michael Hartl's online book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-first_tests) and came across this regex line for his `Guardfile`.

```
watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$})  do |m|
    ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb",
     "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb",
     "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb",
     (m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                       "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]
```

What does the last bit do:

`(m[1][/_pages/] ? "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" : 
                           "spec/requests/#{m[1].singularize}_pages_spec.rb")]`)

I get that `m[1]` would be the name of the controller, but what does the `[/_pages/]` part accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex on to get a substring out of a string. It returns the first match or `nil` if no matches are found.

```
string = "foobar"
string[/[ab]/] # => "b"
string[/ab/]   # => nil
```

However, Michael uses it as a simple check if the regex matches. You might have seen it written with the `=~` operator:

```
m[1] =~ /_pages/ ? something : something_else
```